# A remote repository, so to speak?

Tags: git, repository

Is it possible to setup a remote repository on a server of mine such that any changes I make to files in my git are immediately pushed to my local machine? So, basically, I'd like the behavior of a local repo but with the files being on a remote server.

Comment: You can still use git for pulling and pushing changes from/to any of your git repositories hosted on any server. [The offcial doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) explains the possibilities in detail.

Comment: I know but I want to see changes live (uncommitted and such).

Comment: `I want to see changes live (uncommitted and such).` please edit the question to explain why - what is the use case here?

Answer (score 2):

There are really only three possibilities here:

- Computer L (your local machine, e.g., your laptop) *doens't have any files at all*.  Computer R (the remote) has all the files.  Then whatever you do on R shows up immediately on L.
- Computer L has files, but something is synchronizing them, e.g., Dropbox or similar.  Then whatever you do on R shows up on L, *later*.  Exactly how much later is a mystery, except to whatever extent whatever synchronizing software you use is capable of being queried or adjusted.
- Computers L and R each have their own separate files.  Changes made on R have no effect on L, and vice versa.

You may be tempted to use the middle one of these three.  If you choose to do that, *do not get Git involved*.  Git is very touchy about exactly which files are updated when and by which command: it needs its own special files to be updated *only by Git itself* and only in a prescribed manner.  Letting some other software touch these files will interfere with Git's operation.  It is not technically impossible to make this work, but it's very tricky and requires a lot of careful "is everything in sync" testing before doing anything significant.

The third of these three is the way Git is *intended* to operate: each computer has *its own* Git repository, with *its own* commits and *its own* branches.  The two Gits can call each other up.  Usually your laptop L calls the remote server R since remote service requires authentication, which Git itself *does not provide* and which is a complex matter since it involves security: passwords, keyed access, public/private-key encryption, one-time pads, zero-knowledge proofs, and/or other methods of securely proving that you are in fact you, and not someone else just claiming to *be* you.

Anyway, with one Git having telephoned the other over the Internet and proven who it's representing, the two Gits can now have a conversation.  One might say, in effect, *I have commit X.*  The reply is either: *oh, hey, I don't have commit X, give it to me* or *I already have commit X*.  This exchanging works based on the commit *hash IDs*, which are those big ugly [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) numbers that you see in `git log` output: each commit gets a unique number as its hash ID.

Having exchanged commits—if you use `git fetch` you *get* commits *from* them, and if you use `git push` you *give* commits *to* them—your Git and their Git can now have all the same commits, depending on who had more commits than the other.  (Sometimes you might need to use both fetch and push, to get reasonably well synchronized.)

Once your Git has the right commits, *then* you have your Git *extract* their commit(s), or *combine* one of their latest commits with one of yours, or whatever else you need to do.  Each commit holds a permanent archive of *every* file, in a special, read-only, compressed and de-duplicated fashion.

Then, whether you've made a new combining commit, or are just choosing one of the existing commits, you have Git *extract* this commit into a *working tree* area.  These are the files you see and work on/with.  These files exist locally, so you do not have to wait for the server on R to send them over.  They are *always* there, available, entirely locally, even if the Internet is cut off for a while.

The cost of this is some degree of duplication of files.  The Git archive-y commits exist in *both computers*.  But Git's file compression is pretty remarkable, at least for ordinary text files (though it's not very good at all for large binary files such as JPG images).  The duplication also provides a form of backup.  Overall, it's usually a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a server running on one of the device and conduct polling at small intervals.
There are many syncing algorithms that you can use (if you plan to scale it up for multiple edits across various devices) example [Differential Synchronization](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can setup a git repo to act like that and it's quite the opposite of what Git stands for, since Git is a **distributed** version control system. Maybe another version control system such as SVN fits better your use case.

Comment: And why do you think a DVCS like git doesn't fit the requirement. Please explain.

Comment: How would using svn better suit the use case?